# hg+svn clone repository error

Tags: python, svn, mercurial, swig

i'm trying to clone svn repository on windows as explained here:

> https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion

and here:

> https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion

i'm normally using x64 2.6.6 python but i also need 32-bit so i have 32bit 2.7 into which i've put swig python svn bindings from

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

problem is when i clone mercurial seems to use 2.6.6 which does not have binding hence i guess this error:

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
**  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.1)
** Extensions loaded: hgsubversion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 42, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 27, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 64, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 683, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 465, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 737, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 691, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 680, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 456, in check
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 139, in wrap
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 456, in check
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\wrappers.py", line 495, in c
lone
    orig(ui, source, dest, **opts)
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 456, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1157, in clone
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 184, in wrap
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\wrappers.py", line 484, in h
gclonewrapper
    data['srcrepo'], data['dstrepo'] = orig(ui, *args, **opts)
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 350, in clone
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2265, in clone
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\svnrepo.py", line 70, in wra
pper
    return fn(self, *args, **opts)
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\svnrepo.py", line 89, in pul
l
    return wrappers.pull(self, remote, heads, force)
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\wrappers.py", line 353, in p
ull
    firstrun)
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\replay.py", line 67, in conv
ert_rev
    svn.get_replay(r.revnum, editor, meta.revmap.oldest)
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\svnwrap\svn_swig_wrapper.py"
, line 403, in get_replay
    self.init_ra_and_client()
  File "C:\Users\IG\Documents\hgsubv\hgsubversion\svnwrap\svn_swig_wrapper.py"
, line 226, in init_ra_and_client
    raise common.SubversionConnectionException(msg)
hgext_hgsubversion.svnwrap.common.SubversionConnectionException: Failed to open Subversion repository;
```

i've put 2.7 before 2.6.6 in ENV VARIABLES and when into cmd i write python i see 2.7 as my defult python dist.

what am i missing?

thanks

EDIT:

i use tortoise hg for 64-bit windows with built in mercurial, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You  forgot to include last line of error message "please try running 'svn ls
URL-of-repo' for details.", but you done `svn ls`, sure?

If it's big repo with deep history anyway it's **not recommended to clone from start to HEAD**. Clone *some revisions* and pull rest

Or read [this topic](http://hg.notalon.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issue/180/failure-cloning-a-subversion-repository) for subvertpy, subvertpy binding details and Subvertpy Binary for Win32

Comment: haven't tried svn ls, and you're right there is a lot of history, but atm i pulled with visual svn demo, it contains svn command line but it is only temp solution, thanks, i'll investigate this some more